# I traded XRP for BTC. How do I withdraw my bitcoins from ripple.com?

Tags: ripple

I traded XRP for BTC. How do I withdraw my bitcoins from ripple.com? I guess I need to withdraw to bitstamp.net somehow?

Comment: See https://ripple.com, https://ripple.com/wiki, and/or https://ripple.com/forum . You probably have BTC via Bitstamp, if so see https://bitstamp.net/account/deposit/ripple

Answer (score 7):

If you traded on the Bitstamp/BTC exchange, then log into your Bitstamp account (create one if you don't have one), select 'Deposit' and then select 'Ripple'. Follow the instructions.

Answer (score 3):

Ripple can't hold Bitcoin natively. Instead, you have an IOU from somebody saying that they owe you 3 BTC. Now, you can go to the person who issued that IOU, and ask for those bitcoins in exchange for cancelling the IOU. If you don't like the terms that they give you for the IOU (example: they only deal in amounts larger than 5 BTC), then you can trade that IOU for one from a different gateway.

To figure out what IOU's you hold, look at the trust tab of your client.

Answer (score 1):

As David Schwartz notice, it can be done via Bitstamp.

Today, Bitstamp require an authentication.

[image]

Means:

> TO VERIFY YOUR ACCOUNT PLEASE SUBMIT
>
> 1.) a valid government issued ID,
>   acceptable high quality images of documents are: international
>   passport (double page) national ID card (both sides) driver's license
>   (both sides)
>
> 2.) a proof of residency, acceptable scanned images of paper documents are: bank statement utility bill for utilities consumed at your home
>   address tax return, council tax certificate of residency issued by a
>   government or a local government authority You can also submit other
>   documents to serve as proof of residency such as; government-issued
>   documents, judicial authority-issued documents, documents issued by a
>   public agency / authority, utility service company, or similar
>   regulated service providing companies.

---

**The great news**, that you can withdraw bitcoins directly from ripple.com client.

Read this, 
https://ripple.com/blog/bitcoin-bridge-lets-ripple-users-make-payments-to-bitcoin-accounts/

[image]

If you push "Send XRP" button, it magically convert xrp to btc and send coins to you.